# `expo-face-detector` not detecting faces in landscape mode

Tags: react-native, expo, landscape, expo-camera

I am working on an Expo managed react-native project, using `expo-face-detector` to detect faces. It is working fine on Portrait mode. But when I changed `"orientation": "landscape"` in app.json, I am getting 0 face result or sometimes 2 face results in `onFacesDetected` callback.

```
<Camera
    type={Camera.Constants.Type.front}
    onFacesDetected={res => console.log(res.faces.length)}
    faceDetectorSettings={{
       detectLandmarks: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorLandmarks.all,
       mode: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorMode.accurate,
       runClassifications: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorClassifications.all,
       minDetectionInterval: 500,
       tracking: false
    }}
/>
```

I am using the following package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "expo": "~48.0.6",
    "expo-camera": "~13.2.1",
    "expo-face-detector": "~12.1.1",
    "expo-image": "~1.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.4",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.8",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution or work around this issue? I am having a very similar issue, only on iOS in landscape. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to the expo-face-detector library not handling landscape mode face detection. One possible approach is to use the front camera and manually detect faces, using the front camera frames in landscape mode. You can use expo-camera to access frames from the camera and process them with a face detection library that supports landscape mode. For example you can use react-native-camera

1. `expo install react-native-camera`

Full code:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'react-native-camera';
import { FaceDetector } from 'react-native-camera';

const CameraComponent = () => {
  const cameraRef = useRef<Camera>(null);

  const handleCameraReady = async () => {
    // Start processing frames here (e.g., start face detection loop)
  };

  const handleFacesDetected = ({ faces }: FaceDetector.FaceDetectionResult) => {
    console.log('Number of faces detected:', faces.length);
    // Process the detected faces here
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Camera
        ref={cameraRef}
        type={Camera.Constants.Type.front}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        onCameraReady={handleCameraReady}
        onFacesDetected={handleFacesDetected}
        faceDetectionClassifications={
          Camera.Constants.FaceDetection.Classifications.all
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default CameraComponent;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt help on my case. I dont have the landscape orientation locked on the app, so the viewer already rotates correctly when the device rotates from portrait to landscape or the other way around, so viewer is not an issue. But the face detection still doesnt work consistently on landscape

Comment: I will try later and update you.

Comment: Changed full code, let me know!